# Radius of Convergence of Sum of two Series.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

Hi all, I know there are similar questions on here, but none deal with the fact of trying to prove that $T \geq min\{R,S\}$.
Intuitively this doesn't make sense to me, If you have, $$\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{} (a_{n}+b_{n})x^n$$ Shouldn't this be equal to ;
$$\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{} (a_{n}+b_{n})x^n=\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{} (a_{n})x^n+\sum_{n=n_{0}}^{} (b_{n})x^n$$
And intuitively ...at least for me, shouldn't the radius of convergence of the LHS be the minimum of the radii of convergence of the two power series on the RHS?
I can't think of a case for when it is larger than the minimum  of the radii of convergence of the two power series on the RHS.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: As a hint: If $R\neq S$, then you have $T = \min \{R,S\}$. Only if $R = S$ can strict inequality occur. Does that help seeing how it may occur?

Comment: A trivial example is taking $a_n = 1$ and $b_n = -1$. Both have radius of convergence $1$ but the sum has radius of convergence $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct: as long as both series converge (that is, as long as $\lvert x\rvert\leq\min\{R,S\}$, so that you are inside both radii of convergence), you have
$$
\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}(a_n+b_n)x^n=\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}a_nx^n+\sum_{n=n_0}^{\infty}b_nx^n.
$$
But, this doesn't mean that $\min\{R,S\}$ is the best that we can do!

For an example of that, think about the case where there is a lot of cancellation of terms in $a_n+b_n$.  Do you see what I'm getting at?

Answer (score 0):

But you already know the answer to your question: let $(a_n)$ have radius of convergence $1$ and $(b_n)$ have radius of convergence $1/2$. Certainly then, putting $(c)=(a)+(b)$, the new $(c)$ will have radius of convergence $1/2$.

Now what about $(c)+(-b)$? Both these series have radius of convergence $1/2$, but their sum is $(a)$.