# Radius of convergence of the Taylor's series of a sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the open ball of center $x_{0}\in \mathbb{R}^{k}$ with $k\geq1$ and radius $R>0$. 
Let $f$, $ g $ and $ h $ be three positive real analytic functions on $D$ such that 
$$f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$$ for all $x\in D$. Suppose there exists a positive number $r<R$ such that the Taylor's series of $f$ converges for $|x-x_{0}|<r$. Can we conclude that so do the Taylors series of the two other functions?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/762826/radius-of-convergence-of-sum-of-two-series?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** What happens if $h(x)=C-g(x)$? where $C$ is a well chosen constant?

Pick for example $D=(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

**Note** I am assuming that $D$ is a subset of the domain of the analiticity, otherwise the question is badly posted: if the functions are analytic on $D$ and you only look inside $D$, how do you define $r$?

Comment: Sorry! I corrected the question...

Comment: @M.Rahmat  Check the edit.

Comment: I did. Is every thing clear now?